# C++ - Looking For "help"

Tags: c++, function

Okay, so I've actually been programming in C++ for quite a while now, but I am currently stumped on something that's probably *very* obvious. I decided to write a basic calculator for fun. Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, the whole lot. As you can see below, I have an int variable called choice looking for either 1, 2, 3, or 4. Once chosen, it will call the corresponding function. However, I decided I want the ability to, at any time, type "help" to show help. How can I do this? I know I could simply make choice a string, but I feel that would just be putting a bandaid on the problem (Wouldn't help for future problems). I want to, at any time, catch a "help". However, using another if() statement to catch "help" would obviously give me an error - as choice is an int.

Please help me, I am sure this is very simple, but for some reason I can't figure it out!

```
#include <iostream>

int firstnum;
int secondnum;

int multiplication(){
    std::cout << "Multiplication chosen. Please enter first number." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> firstnum;
    std::cout << "Please enter second number." << endl;
    std::cin >> secondnum;
    std::cout << "Your answer is: " << firstnum * secondnum << "." << std::endl;
}

int division(){
    std::cout << "Division chosen. Please enter first number." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> firstnum;
    std::cout << "Please enter second number." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> secondnum;
    std::cout << "Your answer is: " << firstnum / secondnum << "." << std::endl;
}

int addition(){
    std::cout << "Addition chosen. Please enter first number." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> firstnum;
    std::cout << "Please enter second number." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> secondnum;
    std::cout << "Your answer is: " << firstnum + secondnum << "." << std::endl;
}

int subtraction(){
    std::cout << "Subtraction chosen. Please enter first number." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> firstnum;
    std::cout << "Please enter second number." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> secondnum;
    std::cout << "Your answer is: " << firstnum - secondnum << "." << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    int choice;
    std::cout << "Calculator." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Multiplication: 1. Division: 2. Addition: 3. Subtraction: 4. Help: help." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> choice;
    if(choice == 1){
        multiplication();
    }
    if(choice == 2){
        division();
    }
    if(choice == 3){
        addition();
    }
    if(choice == 4){
        subtraction();
    }

////if the user types "help" it will show help.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: Oh, no, you read my question right? I want the user to be able to type "help". It has nothing to do with bypassing the stackoverflow filter.

Comment: Sorry, I have to +1 this if only for the horrible pun :)

Comment: Oh ic. I didn't actually read the question because it was tl;dr. But the word "help" is (under some circumstances) blocked from titles because they correlate very strongly with low question quality. And based on your title, it seemed like the quotes you put around it was to get around that filter. My bad.

Comment: @Mysticial: thou shalt not jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 5):

I would just change choice to a std::string

```
std::string   choice;
std::cin >> choice;

if (choice == "1")    { .... }
if (choice == "help") { .... }
```

But I would also change the if statements structure.
Rather than a list of `if statements` I would use a map. That maps the command to a function call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

int one()
{
    std::cout << "one\n";
}
int two()
{
    std::cout << "two\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<int()> >     action = {{"one", one}, {"two", two}};

    auto act = action.find("one");
    act->second();

}
```

Comment: Sorry, as I said, that seems like it'd only be putting a bandaid on the problem.

Comment: I'd even do away with the "xxx chosen" part and store `std::function`s that are mostly filled with `std::plus` and the like. Then there's just one set of statements to get the two numbers.

Comment: @SydZ: Why does it seem that way?

Comment: While changing the int to a string would work, it just seems to be avoiding a real solution. I am trying to learn C++, and this seems like a pretty basic thing I should know how to do. Check for a string.

Comment: @SydZ: You have it backwards. Normally you read a line (into a string). Then see if it will convert into another type (like a number). See boost::lexical_cast.

Comment: @SydZ This is a "real" solution. C++ has no way to know whether your user intended their input to be a string or an integer. Since you can't store a string in an int, but you can store the string equivalent of an int in a string, then the latter is the way to go if you want the user to be able to input both. It's up to you to write code to differentiate between the two. The same principle applies to text inputs in GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

I like using the Command Pattern for stuff like this. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Basically you have a `Command` class/interface such as:

```
abstract class Command
{
    virtual void run() = 0;
}
```

and then have different commands that inherit from that:

```
class HelpCommand : Command
{
     virtual void run()
     {
         // do stuff
     }
}
```

Then in the handler that gets commands from the user, you would have a map of `string` to `Command`. So when the user enters a command (eg. 'help') it gets the appropriate command from the map and then calls its `run()` method.

```
unordered_map< string, Command* > commands;
commands[ "help" ] = new HelpCommand();

// ...

// get input
commands[ input ]->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it the way you described, you'd first need to read your input into a stringm check if 'help' was entered and if not, if the input can be parsed as an integer. Then you'd parse the integer and call your other functions as normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you said that by using string in that program would be like putting a band aid on the problem, and may cause future issue, why not making another string variable, then later on convert it into numbers if it's viable.
Here's your coding  that I've modified to that purpose.

Example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream.h>

int firstnum;
int secondnum;
void multiplication();
void division();
void addition();
void subtraction();
void help();



int main(){
    int choice=NULL;
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Calculator." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Multiplication: 2. Division: 3. Addition: 4. Subtraction: 5. Help: help." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Input : ";
    std::cin >> input;

    if ((input == "help")||(input == "Help")||(input == "HELP"))    {   choice=5;   }
    else {
        istringstream intinput(input);
        intinput>>choice;
    }



    switch(choice){
    case 1: multiplication();   break;
    case 2: division();   break;
    case 3: addition();   break;
    case 4: subtraction();   break;
    case 5: help();   break;
    }

////if the user types "help" it will show help.

    return 0;
}




// BEGIN FUNCTIONS!--------------------------------------

void multiplication(){
    std::cout << "Multiplication chosen. Please enter first number : ";
    std::cin >> firstnum;
    std::cout << "Please enter second number : ";
    std::cin >> secondnum;
    std::cout << "Your answer is : " << firstnum * secondnum << "." << std::endl;
}

void division(){
    std::cout << "Division chosen. Please enter first number : ";
    std::cin >> firstnum;
    std::cout << "Please enter second number : ";
    std::cin >> secondnum;
    std::cout << "Your answer is: " << firstnum / secondnum << "." << std::endl;
}

void addition(){
    std::cout << "Addition chosen. Please enter first number : ";
    std::cin >> firstnum;
    std::cout << "Please enter second number : ";
    std::cin >> secondnum;
    std::cout << "Your answer is: " << firstnum + secondnum << "." << std::endl;
}

void subtraction(){
    std::cout << "Subtraction chosen. Please enter first number : ";
    std::cin >> firstnum;
    std::cout << "Please enter second number : ";
    std::cin >> secondnum;
    std::cout << "Your answer is: " << firstnum - secondnum << "." << std::endl;
}

void help(){
    std::cout << "A simple help menu.. : ";
}
```

Note that I've modified some of your code because of efficiency and aesthetic reason ; )

Comment: This way, your choice variable still stay as integer.